# VMware bridged mode is not working, but NAT mode works fine

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, bridge

I recently updated my PC and found out that the bridged mode of VMware Workstation Player 17 stopped working, however NAT mode works fine.

Host OS is Windows 11 and guest OS is Ubuntu 18.04.

I've tried:

- Restored defaults using Virtual Network Editor.

  [image: screenshot here]
- Checked network adapter setting.

  [image: screenshot here]
- Enabled VMware Bridge Protocol for Wi-Fi.

  [image: screenshot here]

Everything looks fine to me, but the issue persists.

Comment: I am in VMware here. Bridged networking works fine. Is your Host Machine connected to a router;?

Comment: Yes, and the NAT mode of VMware works, that's why I'm confused.

Comment: Maybe do this:  Make sure your machines are backed up.  Uninstall VMware Player.  Restart. Install VMware Player fresh and check Bridged Networking after this.

Comment: Also if on Wireless, make sure you are in Private Mode.

Comment: New version of VMware Workstation out last night. Also try updating VMware Player.

Comment: Thank you John, I will try what you said!

Comment: I have the same issue with "Bridged" network not working but NAT one working fine! Win10 Pro host as well. VM guest OS tried various OS (Lin, Win) result the same. Any ideas how to get it resolved?

Comment: I just noticed that bridged network doesn't allow DHCP to work. In case IP/MASK/GW settings are set manually - network can work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue.
all what you need to do go under virtualNetworkEditor and on Bridge change the field "Bridged to" from automatic to network interface connected on your host machine

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This solved my issue, also consider excluding unwanted network interfaces from Automatic settings.